# How can I show SQL Server LOGS (2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, exception

I'm trying to track the error thrown by SQL Server 2005. The problem is SQL Server reports it in my native language so it's hard for me to google it.

I think that the core issue would be avialable in English in SQL Server LOGS. I'm running SQL Server Management Studio Express, going to "Management" node, and then SQL Server Logs. I can see the list of logs but I cannot enter them, the only available option in context menu is Refresh.

Could you help me to show the contents of those logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the Express version of the Management Studio can show ERRORLOGs. The alternative is to open the ERRORLOG file in notepad, as is an ordinary text file located usually in \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.EXPRESS\MSSQL\LOG

Another alternative is to open a query window and execute this:

```
exec xp_readerrorlog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1021

HTH